# Where can I store a file that's guaranteed to be readable by every possible program? (Use case is DLLs claiming a COM)

Tags: c#, windows, dll, serial-port

It is entirely possible I'm going about this entirely the wrong way, but here is what I'm doing:

I have a device that is communicating with a DLL over a COM port. This works fine for a single program, however I need multiple programs to be running, each updating with the state of the device.

Since I can't work out how to share access to a COM port, my solution is that each DLL checks for the existance of a timestamped file. If the file is there, the DLL goes into 'slave' mode and just reads the state of the device from the file. If the file doesn't exist or is over 30ms old, the DLL appoints itself 'master', claims the COM port, and writes the file itself.

(The device can also be sent instructions, so the master will have to handle collecting and sending the slaves' requests somehow, but I can deal with that later. Also I might want the DLLs to be aware of each other, so if one is causing problems then the user can be told about it - again, will get to this later.)

My immediate problem now is, where to store this file/possible collection of files? It must:

- be somewhere that doesn't force the programs using the DLLs to have admin privileges or anything else that means they can't "just run".
- be always the same place, not somewhere that might change based on some outside factor. Googling has shown me things like, "Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments" (in C#) but if that location is sometimes C:\ProgramData and other times C:\Users\Public then we'll get two parallel masters, only one of which can claim the COM.
- work on as many Windowses as possible (all the way back to XP if I can get away with it) because no one wants to maintain more versions than necessary.
- preferably, be somewhere non-technical users won't see it. Quite apart from confusing/scaring them, it just looks unprofessional, doesn't it?

Two sidenotes:

- I looked at using the Registry and learned there's a time cost to reading it. The DLLs need to be reading with a period of maybe 10ms, so I assume the Registry is a bad idea.
- After we get this working on Windows, we need to turn around and address Android, OSX, Linux, Mac, etc, etc, so I'm trying to bear that in mind when deciding how we structure everything.

EDIT:

I should add for context that we're releasing the DLL and letting other devs create apps that use it. We want them to work as frictionlessly as possible, without for example requiring the user install anything first, or the dev needing to jump through a bunch of hoops to be sure it will work.

Comment: `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments` won't change on a single machine. It might not be the same between machines running different versions of Windows, or indeed different core languages (as opposed to OS UI language), of course.

Comment: You can write a service that starts a listener the reports the status.  The service can be started when the PC starts.

Comment: @John - I didn't know that. Has that just solved my problem then?

Comment: @jdweng - I'm not sure that's ideal given how I expect things to be used - I'll edit the question to add some context.

Comment: Possibly. I believe even XP had c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\, which I assume that special folder maps to.

Comment: @John - Cool. In that case, ought you to make that an answer and I'll confirm it? Unless someone else wants to hop in first and tell me I'm addressing the whole problem wrong and here's a better way.

Comment: Wouldn't using a named-pipe with unlimited instances be better than a disk file?

Comment: @eryksun - I'll admit my ignorance. What advantages/disadvantages would a named-pipe have over a file?